# HTML- Table is wider than specified and content contained inside of it

Tags: html, html-table, width

I will post my HTML, but I'm not sure how the first table (which contains all subsequent tables) is always an additional 2-3 pixels wider than the rest of the content. I have spent the last 2 hours troubleshooting what I believe should be an easy fix... but I can't seem to find any other areas that may be causing the problem. I apologize if the solution is obvious, I haven't designed a website since I was in high school so my skills are a little rusty/aged.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Piedmont Wealth Solutions</title>

<style type="text/css"><!--
a:link {
color:000000; font-face:arial; font-size:10pt; text-decoration:none
}
a:visited {
color:000000; font-face:arial; font-size:10pt; text-decoration:none
}
a:active {
color:000000; font-face:arial; font-size:10pt; text-decoration:none
}
a:hover {
color:000000; font-face:arial; font-size:10pt; text-decoration:underline
}
body {
color:Body; font-size:10pt; font-family:Arial;
}
td {
color:Body; font-size:10pt; font-family:Arial
}
--></style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="e9e9e9" background="page_bg.gif" font face="arial" size="10" valign="top" topmargin="0" leftmargin="180">


<table width="537" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top" align="left" height="100%" border="0" bgcolor="265b78">

<tr width="537" valign="top" align="left">
<td valign="top" align="left" width="36" background="table_bg_left.gif">
</td>


<td width="501" valign="top" align="left">
<!------banner/nav----->

<table width="501" valign="top" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="c5c5c5">
<tr valign="top" align="left" border="0">



<img src="banner_nav.jpg" border="0" valign="top" align="left">
<img src="content_top_spacer.jpg" border="0" valign="top" align="left">

</td>
</tr>
</table>


<!------content------>
<table width="501" height="350" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
<tr valign="top" align="left">
<td valign="top" align="left" width="356" bgcolor="f5F8Fa">

<img src="aboutus_header.jpg" border="0" valign="top"> 
<br>
<br>


Content
</td>


<td valign="top" width="144" bgcolor="f0f3f5">

<img src="news_header.jpg" border="0" align="left" valign="top"> <br><br>


google news feed
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!------address/disclaimer------>

<table width="501" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  height="45%" border="0" valign="top" align="left" bgcolor="265b78">
<tr valign="top" align="left">
<td valign="top" align="left" height="15" bgcolor="aac6d5">
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top" align="left">
<td valign="top" align="left" height="15" bgcolor="7da6bc">
</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" align="left">
<td valign="top" align="left">

<img src="bottom_disclosure.jpg" align="left" valign="top" border="0">

</td>
</tr>
</table>


</td>
</tr>
</table>


</td>
</tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables should not be used for layout purposes, that's what CSS is for. Tables are for tabular data. With CSS you have a very nice control over the positioning and dimensions of your content.

[Here's a collection of reasons why you should opt for CSS.](http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/13-reasons-why-css-is-superior-to-tables-in-website-design/)

[This is (IMHO) the best book for a head start.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596802447)

Comment: Adding on from what Dennis said, you should always assign a `DOCTYPE` to every page (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp), this avoids entering quirks mode which can have rather noticeable differences within different browsers, see Cross Browser (or Multi Browser) Compatibility .

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am not a web designer and only doing this to save my company money. I may look into it if nobody else helps, but my day-to-day job is dealing with clients, not coding. If this can be fixed in HTML, then I am done with the layout and can get the site up and running.

Comment: You mean as a wealth solutions company you have no money for a proper web design? That's bad. Nevertheless CSS is the only reliable solution, especially when a 2 pixel offset matters.

Comment: We have the cash, but would rather spend it on operations technology because we don't need a super fancy and integrated website. Most designers in the area want $3000+ for a template and a few added services. That is not worth the money for what we need.

Comment: As I said, use CSS if you need reliable layout/positioning, or live with the drawbacks of tables (and eventually spend more time and frustration on trying to make it work anyway.) If my answer above was helpful, then let me know by accepting it. Thanks and good luck.